# Label connection with textField in java

Tags: swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel, jtextfield

I wanted to take some value in currently available in label and add(calculate) with number
and display on the text field but there is errors

```
private void ch13ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     

    r1=Integer.parseInt(tLabel.getText());  //r2 and r1 are integers               

    // error .. It says "Void type not allowed here"
    r2 = Integer.parseInt(tLabel.setText(String.valueOf("3")));    


    result=r1+r2; 
    creaditTxt.setText(result+"");
}
```

Then how do i solve this problem?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish. Explain it in more detail, with how many labels you have, their variable names and what `r1` and `r2` are. Also what exactly are you trying to accomplish in the error line?

Answer (score 0):

`setText()` returns `void`. So by doing this

```
r2 = Integer.parseInt(tLabel.setText(String.valueOf("3")));
```

you're saying that `r2` = void. That's not possible.

You may want to have 2 textfields instead and a label to display the result

```
public class AddFrame extends JFrame {
    private JLabel result = new JLabel();
    private JTextField number1 = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField number2 = new JTextField(10);
    private JButton addBut = new JButton("Add");

    public AddFrame(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        add(result);
        add(number1);
        add(number2);
        add(addBut);

        addBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText());
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.gettext());
                int total = num1 + num2;
                result.setText(String.valueOf(total));
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                AddFrame frame = new AddFrame();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

}
```